# How to adjust the padding surrounding a matrix's cells?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript featuring a TikZ picture of a matrix with a single cell.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[draw,nodes=draw]
  {
    \node {*}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting image is

[image: A matrix with a single cell]

How can I adjust the padding surrounding the cell? For instance, suppose I wish to get rid of the padding all together. I attempted to add `inner sep=0pt` to the matrix's option list, but then not only did the padding surrounding the cell collapse, but also the padding surrounding the asterisk inside the cell:

[image: inner sep=0]

P.S. If the matrix has more than one cell, I don't wish to alter the spacing between the rows or the spacing between the columns; only the padding inside the matrix that surrounds the entire grid of cells.

Comment: `inner sep=2pt, nodes={draw, inner sep=0}` or `inner sep=0, nodes={draw, inner sep=2pt}`

Comment: @percusse: Thanks, however (1) What if I want to keep the current `inner sep` of the cells, but I don't know what it is? (2) Is there a way to adjust the four margins separately? `inner sep` affects all four of them uniformly.

Comment: inner xsep and ysep are different ways to adjust. also there is `every matrix` style

Comment: @percusse: The `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` partly solve problem #2, but only partly, and only problem #2. As for the `every matrix` style: I don't think that, in itself, it solves either of the problems. For instance, if I add the option `every matrix/.style={inner sep=0pt}` to the `tikzpicture`'s option list, the `inner sep` inside the cell collapses as well as the surrounding padding.

Comment: Can you give an example what you want to do? There are new problems coming up. There are no individual sep values only x and y. Same with outer x and y sep

Comment: @percusse: OK, but what about problem #1? Is there a way to retain the cells' inner sep without specifying it explicitly?

Comment: you can get the current xsep and ysep values `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}` if that's a concern and reset the nodes after setting `inner sep=0`.